# Mosquitto Secure MQTT connection

Tags: java, ssl, mqtt, iot, mosquitto

My Question is regarding TLS/SSL MQTT connection.
I've installed moaquitto broker from this website.

http://www.eclipse.org/mosquitto/download/

and done with simple subscribe/publish using paho eclipse library in java.
then I created X509 certificates using bouncycastle in java.
but now I am stuck at server configurations regarding these certificates.I need to use different certificates for different topics on same broker.
What I found is the following mosquitto-auth-plug.

https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug

But here  in mosquitto_auth_plugin we need to  define backend databases holding username and password for authentication. How can we save certificates here? as I stated above I am creating X509 rootCA for server and X509 certificates for client.I am quit confused about it.

Is there any other/better way to acknowledge server regarding these certificates? Can this purpose be achieved using anyother broker like HiveMQ,ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ?

Comment: @hardllib. here. can u help???